# When referring to HIPAA legislation, would the 2013 Omnibus rule be considered all inclusive or refer only to the additions in the Omnibus rule?

Tags: legal-terms, hipaa

When referring to the HIPAA 2013 Omnibus rule, should this be read as HIPPA all-inclusive, from inception; up-to and including the changes introduced in the 2013 Omnibus rule or should this be read as only the changes introduced in the 2013 Omnibus rule?